java socket compression
I'm having a strange issue with a java project that uses sockets, Inflater, and Deflater, and I think I just need another set of eyes on it.
I'm seeing reads on the socket server that just have the 2 header bytes, 789c, which doesn't finish the inflate operation. Then I receive a full payload with the header bytes again at the beginning, and when I try to continue the inflate operation with this payload, I get an error:
2024-04-07T08:12:47.850-07:00  INFO 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [           main] demo.server.ServerApplication            : Started ServerApplication in 0.417 seconds (process running for 0.745)
2024-04-07T08:12:53.581-07:00 DEBUG 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [Pool-1-worker-2] demo.server.MessageListener              : readCount: 2
2024-04-07T08:12:53.583-07:00 DEBUG 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [Pool-1-worker-2] demo.server.MessageListener              : readOutputStream byte array: 789c
2024-04-07T08:12:53.583-07:00 DEBUG 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [Pool-1-worker-2] demo.server.MessageListener              : inflater not finished and doesn't needs input, calling inflater.inflate
2024-04-07T08:12:53.583-07:00 DEBUG 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [Pool-1-worker-2] demo.server.MessageListener              : readCount: 13
2024-04-07T08:12:53.583-07:00 DEBUG 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [Pool-1-worker-2] demo.server.MessageListener              : readOutputStream byte array: 789cf348cdc9c95730000009e60245
2024-04-07T08:12:53.583-07:00 DEBUG 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [Pool-1-worker-2] demo.server.MessageListener              : inflater not finished and doesn't needs input, calling inflater.inflate
2024-04-07T08:12:53.584-07:00 ERROR 14688 --- [compressed-socket-demo-server] [Pool-1-worker-2] demo.server.MessageListener              : 
MessageListener error
java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid stored block lengths
    at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytesBytes(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:376) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:470) ~[na:na]
    at demo.server.MessageListener.listen(MessageListener.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at demo.server.SeverSocketListener.lambda$start$0(SeverSocketListener.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1556) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:507) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1491) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2073) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2035) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:187) ~[na:na]

Here's the relevant portion of the server:
public void listen() {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();

            byte[] readBuff = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream readOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
            byte[] inflateBuff = new byte[1024];
            int readCount;
            int inflateCount = 0;
            while ((readCount = inputStream.read(readBuff)) != -1) {
                log.debug("readCount: {}", readCount);
                readOutputStream.write(readBuff, 0, readCount);
                log.debug("readOutputStream byte array: {}", hexFormat.formatHex(readOutputStream.toByteArray()));
                inflater.setInput(readOutputStream.toByteArray());
                while (inflater.getRemaining() > 0 && !inflater.finished() && !inflater.needsInput()) {
                    log.debug("inflater not finished and doesn't needs input, calling inflater.inflate");
                    inflateCount += inflater.inflate(inflateBuff);
                }
                if (inflater.finished()) {
                    log.debug("inflater finished, handling message");
                    handleMessage(Arrays.copyOfRange(inflateBuff, 0, inflateCount));
                    inflater.reset();
                    inflateCount = 0;
                    readOutputStream.close();
                    readOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | DataFormatException e) {
            log.error("MessageListener error", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

and a bit of the client:
@Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4943)) {
            OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Hello ").append(i);
                writeMessage(socketOutputStream, message.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
        }
    }

    private void writeMessage(OutputStream socketOutputStream, byte[] message) {
        log.debug("Writing {}", message);
        try {
            DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(socketOutputStream);
            deflaterOutputStream.write(message);
            deflaterOutputStream.finish();
            deflaterOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

I've pushed the full maven multi-module project with server and client to a public github repo here: https://github.com/gadams00/compressed-socket-demo.
I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what.

I did a bit more testing with InflaterInputStream as suggested in a comment. It doesn't seem that InflaterInputStream has any way to handle remaining input.
Some additional background:
The java socket server is a part of an integration with a third party socket client that sends messages compressed with zlib. It does not wait for a response on the socket before sending another message.
In the java socket server, I'm using an InflaterInputStream wrapped around the client socket input stream. When InflaterInputStream fills into its internal buffer, it contains multiple compressed messages. The InflaterInputStream doesn't seem to provide any way to deal with remaining input. Once the contained Inflater is finished, any subsequent reads will return -1. Am I missing some way to make this work, or do I need to use Inflater directly myself so that I can deal with input that contains multiple compressed messages?

Why aren’t you using InflaterInputStream? Throw your reading code away and use it. And use both deflater/inflater streams for the life of the socket, at both ends. Not one per message.

I was using InflaterInputStream, you can see it commented out in the repository, but I was getting an error and switched to using Inflater directly to be able to log the bytes. I'll try keeping the same inflater and deflater streams as you suggest.

I tried using InflaterInputStream on the server/reader side, and DeflaterOutputStream on the client/writer side, with both sides keeping the same streams for the life of the socket, and I get java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: write beyond end of stream on the second write to the DeflaterOutputStream, with or without finish and flush calls.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that in order for the reading side to be able to deflate a message and see anything, we have to finish the compression on the writer side. It seems that once you call finish on DeflaterOutputStream, you can no longer write to it, and must open a new DeflaterOutputStream.

In my use case, the client side connects to the server socket, a handshake takes place where the server sends some startup information to the client, then the client continuously sends deflated payloads, without waiting between payloads for any kind of response from the server. This causes the socket input stream reads in the server to contain potentially multiple deflated payloads. I initially wanted to somehow control the sends on the client side to make it so that reads on the server side only ever contain one payload, but I think that's just how tcp streams work. Also, this is for an integration with a third party that isn't likely to change the protocol.
InflaterInputStream isn't built for this use case, and it's not a good fit for an InputStream at all, since InputStreams read bytes, with nothing in the interface to indicate the end of one compressed byte array and the beginning of the next. InflaterInputStream is built to inflate a single deflated byte stream, as soon as the deflater is finished, the InflaterInputStream is put into an EOF state, and all subsequent reads will return -1, with no way to reset the InflaterInputStream without opening a new one. The problem with that is that the internal buffer in InflaterInputStream can have more data already read from the socket after the end of the first compressed byte array, with no way to recover that data an provide it to the next inflate.
The solution for me was to read from the socket's input stream on the server side and manage the Inflater myself, specifically dealing with remaining bytes and calling setInput appropriately. I also had to take care to deal with partial payloads from the end of the read buffer continued in the next read. This resolved my issue.
